# CSS spacing problem. need fresh eyes.(should be easy)

Tags: css

okay so this minor yet MASSIVE annoyace is that, i have a site im working on, and a panel in particular is behaving oddly.

i have a generic box div which will hold 2 images, one ontop of the other and i want absolutely no spacing inbetween them.

problem is that no matter what i do, when on dev mode it behaves normally, but when i publish, i see space inbetween the images.

normally, i dont set widths/height etc depending on what im doing but for this...its been SUCH the major pain that i declared heights on everything to make sure im not missing a few digits here or there, and still nothing.

heres an example of what is happening. (on my server)
http://somdowprod.net/4testing/erase

if you look there, theres about a 5px space between the pic on top and the tst pic on bottom no matter the browser (ff/ie/chrome) ...thing is behaving like tables.......

heres the code for the inline css im testing/isolated:

```
   <style type="text/css">

body{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}

.nospacedammit{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#portS_mainW{ width:400px; height:500px; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
#portS_mainW img{ margin:0px; padding:0px; }
</style>
```

and heres the basic html for this panel:

```
    <div id="portS_mainW">
<span class="nospacedammit"><img src="images/xrodemo.jpg" alt="xro" width="400" height="300"/></span>
<span class="nospacedammit"><img src="images/erase.png" alt="xro" width="400" height="200"/></span>
</div>
```

ive added heights to make 100% sure about the #s, ive added margins/paddings to zero out on every element to again make sure theres no spacing.

ive also wrapped each image in a span tag, then added an overall everything to zero style to it ....trying to force zero spacing in every way i can thing of. and still nothing.

any ideas, insight i gladly appreciate.

thank you in advance.

Comment: BTW, what font is the text in the top image... that's nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `line-height: 0;` on the `nospacedammit` class. That is the reason that the space is inserted in between the 2 images.

Edit: you need to set the display to `display: block` as well

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `float:left` to your images.  Just tested this in Firefox 3.6 and it works for me :-)

I'm not 100% sure why this happens but my guess would be because none of your elements have any positioning applied to them, leaving it up to the browser to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img class="nospacedammit" src="images/xrodemo.jpg" alt="xro" width="400" height="300"/>
<img class="nospacedammit" src="images/erase.png" alt="xro" width="400" height="200"/>
```

And add a property of display: block; to .nospacedammit